# Slow response in Dialog flow with the warning message

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to use dialogflow fulfillment with the inline editor. But occasionally I get a slow response, and whenever that slow response happens, I get the following warning in the logs

```
Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Initializing firebase-admin may fail
```

It's weird, since I haven't required firebase-admin into my code, it's simply there in package.json as a dependency (and cannot be removed)

Here are the only things that are getting required

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
```

And this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning message is only that - a warning. It does not mean there is a problem. It is probably happening during environment initialization when the Cloud Function is cold started - hence the slightly slower start.

If you are not using `firebase-admin` calls, then you have nothing to worry about.

If you *are* using `firebase-admin`, then you just need to be sure that the environment is referencing the project you expect.